# trouble with mysql_xdevapi extension

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-x-devapi

I am trying to install the `mysql_xdevapi` extension because it's required to use the `NemioApi` bundle for Symfony.I installed all the necessary dependencies for it to work,i.e `protobuf` and `boost` libraries, still , after installing the extension's .dll file, moving it the ext folder and adding the extension to my php.ini file ,I get this error when starting my apache server
`The entry point of the php_SHA256Init procedure is not found in the dynamic link library C:\xaamp\php\ext\php_mysql_xdevapi.dll|`

I think this might be a version incompatibility issue , but I can confirm I installed the latest version of the extension from PECL and the requirements say PHP>= 7.0 and I got PHP 8.2